# C++ How do you get the duration of a mp3 file?

Tags: c++, mp3

I'm trying to get the duration of a list of mp3 files I have, they vary between 3-6 seconds.

I have a working version using `ffprobe`:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include "process.h"
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

string get_audio_file_length(string command)
{
    char buffer[128];
    string result = "";
    // Open pipe to file
    FILE *pipe = popen(command.c_str(), "r");
    if (!pipe)
        return "popen failed!";

    // read till end of process:
    while (!feof(pipe))
    {
        // use buffer to read and add to result
        if (fgets(buffer, 128, pipe) != NULL)
            result += buffer;
    }

    pclose(pipe);
    return result;
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    string file_name = argv[1];
    // depending if ffprobe.exe is in the current directory of the file or added to path variables.
    string length = get_audio_file_length("ffprobe -v error -show_entries format=duration -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 \"" + file_name + "\"");
    cout << length << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Compiling the file `g++ test.cpp -o test` and running below yield the following result:

```sh
>>> test A1.mp3
>>> 5.712000
```

The problem with the above example is it takes roughly 15 seconds or more to find the duration of over 200+ .mp3 files...

Is there a way to optimize this? or a pure C++ method of doing this instead of using ffprobe?

Comment: Find an mp3 library and use that (or even the ffmpeg library itself) creating processes is fairly expensive

Comment: @AlanBirtles I have looked for mp3 libraries, But to no avail.. Would you know of any?

Comment: You can use the various `libav*` libraries that come as part of the `ffmpeg` installation and refer to the `ffprobe` source code as a guide on how to use the APIs.